# Dungeon Finder "Activity Complete", how to correctly leave a group dungeon on console?

Tags: xbox-one, the-elder-scrolls-online

A friend and I joined a random normal dungeon through the Dungeon Finder in Elder Scrolls Online on Xbox One.

After playing through the dungeon and killing the final boss we saw the other 2 players fade out. What is the best and/or "correct" way to leave the dungeon at this point?

Is it possible to return to exactly the point on some map that we were at when our dungeon queue ticket came up?

Or do we just have to teleport to a wayshrine?

My friend logged off, and I teleported to a wayshrine. Now the right side of the screen shows a rather permanent "DUNGEON FINDER" and "Activity Complete". I gather I did not use the "correct" way to leave the dungeon.

I looked through all the menus before teleporting but could not find anything that looked promising, and after noticing the permanent text on the right side, still can't find anything. I assume that logging out and back in will get rid of it but that can't really be right. Or is it?

[image: eso with "Activity Complete" text to the right]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is this is most likely due to you still being in a group that used the finder or was created by the finder. In ESO groups persist even though people log out of the game. In fact, you could even have multiple of your characters in the very same group.

**Just leave the group and everything is fine again.**

As an alternative, open the Dungeon Finder and disable it (not sure if this alternative actually works).

Also since the *One Tamriel* update there's no real/proper way to just return to your previous version as far as I'm aware, although I haven't really played any dungeons since then.

Comment: Since I've only been playing with my friend now we haven't really left the group at all, just having one player as offline from time to time, leaving the group did indeed remove the "Activity Complete" text, which persisted even after reload (but still being in the group).